# Why do I sometimes get requests for root access from unusual applications?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, root-access, malware

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 running a rooted stock firmware, Occasionally I get a popup from my superuser application saying that an application that I did not specifically install or launch has requested root access. I always deny these requests, obviously, but I'm not sure why they happen in the first place.

The most recent was from "Google Backup Transport", which, being a preinstalled application, seems like it shouldn't be asking me for root. [At least one other person](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2335496&page=3) appears to be having the same issue, but I can't seem to find much information about it. I don't remember the previous application names, as it only seems to happen every several weeks or so, but it is not the same application every time.

Could this be indicative of a malware infection? If not, why is it happening?

EDIT: It just happened again - this time it was SyncMLSvc requesting root access - it seems to be a Samsung service.

Comment: What su app are you using?

Comment: It is the free [Superuser app](https://github.com/koush/Superuser) by Koushik Dutta.